# Oracle Builtin String Character Classes

Tags: oracle, string, oracle9i

Does Oracle have built-in string character class constants (digits, letters, alphanum, upper, lower, etc)?

My actual goal is to efficiently return only the digits [0-9] from an existing string.

Unfortunately, we still use Oracle 9, so regular expressions are not an option here.

**Examples**
The field should contain zero to three letters, 3 or 4 digits, then zero to two letters.  I want to extract the digits.

```
String    --> Result
ABC1234YY --> 1234
D456YD    --> 456
455PN     --> 455
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No string constants, but you can do:

```
select translate
      ( mystring
      , '0'||translate (mystring, 'x0123456789', 'x')
      , '0'
      )
from mytable;
```

For example:

```
select translate
      ( mystring
      , '0'||translate (mystring, 'x0123456789', 'x')
      , '0'
      )
from
( select 'fdkhsd1237ehjsdf7623A@L:P' as mystring from dual);

TRANSLAT
--------
12377623
```

If you want to do this often you can wrap it up as a function:

```
create function only_digits (mystring varchar2) return varchar2
is
begin
   return
      translate
         ( mystring
         , '0'||translate (mystring, 'x0123456789', 'x')
         , '0'
         );
end;
/
```

Then:

```
SQL> select only_digits ('fdkhsd1237ehjsdf7623A@L:P') from dual;

ONLY_DIGITS('FDKHSD1237EHJSDF7623A@L:P')
-----------------------------------------------------------------
12377623
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the list for predefined datatypes on Oracle [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/03_types.htm#10531), but you are not going to find what are you looking for.

To extract the numbers of an string you can use some combination of these functions:

- [TO_NUMBER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions145a.htm#1003400), to convert an string to number.
- [REPLACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions102a.htm#78610), to remove occurences.
- [TRANSLATE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions150a.htm#79574), to convert chars.

If you provide a more concise example will be easier to give you a detailed solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use PL/SQL here, another approach is write your own regular expression matcher function.  One starting point is Rob Pike's elegant, very tiny regular expression matcher in Chapter 1 of [Beautiful Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510047).  One of the exercises for the reader is to add character classes.  (You'd first need to translate his 30 lines of C code into PL/SQL.)